# computing the following limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

the first one I got 1 but i wanted to check if i'm correct 
the second one I saw solutions using Riemann summation but I hvent learned it yet so im asking for another way 
the third one I got also 1 I used euler limit but i'm not sure if i'm correct

thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, again "reimann sum". It should be "Riemann sum". How did you solve (b)?

Comment: you arent being helpful

Comment: You aren't helpful, either. Please let us know what you have tried. This is no "do my homework" page.

Comment: the first one I changed it to a^1/n and then I know that the limit of 1/n is 0 so at the end it is 1

Comment: the second one I thought to use the squeez rule but i couldnt come up with the function which is bigger than this one . the third one i just tried to add 1 and to sub 1 to have the form of euler limit

Comment: @AvivBarel : From the popup you saw before typing your Question: "3. When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried".  Your work should be shown in your Question, not strewn through the Comments.  We're not psychic, so it is impossible to skip wasting everyone's time explaining what you already understand but didn't show in your Question.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{n^2+r}$$

$$n^2 \le n^2+r \le n^2+2n+1$$

$$\frac{1}{n^2} \ge \frac{1}{n^2+r} \ge \frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n^2} > \sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n^2+r} > \sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}$$

$$\frac{2n+2}{n^2} > \frac{1}{n^2+r} > \frac{2n+2}{n^2+2n+1}$$

$$ \lim{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+2}{n^2} > \lim{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2+r} > \lim{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+2}{n^2+2n+1}$$

$$ 0 > \lim{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2+r} > 0$$

$$ \Rightarrow \lim{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2+r} = 0$$

Comment: @Eric Thank you. Mistakenly, I assumed it to be $r^2$ instead of r.